# What does "Matrix indexed for..." mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Do you have any idea what "Matrix indexed for..." means in the [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) notation page (page 5)? Can you give an example?

P.S In the Derivatives section of this book I need to know it to get my head round of the equations, particularly Equation (32) in page 8.

Comment: $A_{ij}$ means the matrix element of $A$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column. The $i$ and $j$ are called indices. This notation is an indexing of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you  Ziggurism, but how do you interpret equation (32) in page 8?

Comment: In calculus in three dimensions, you have $\partial x/\partial x=1,\partial x/\partial y=0,\partial x/\partial z=0.$ So the partial derivative vanishes unless you put the same variable in the numerator and denominator. Similarly in the space of matrices, the partial derivative of the $X_{kl}$ element with respect to the $X_{ij}$ element is 0 if they are different, and 1 if they are the same.

Comment: So what are $\delta_{ik}$ and $\delta_{lj}$ defined?

Comment: They are Kronecker deltas. $\delta_{ik}=1$ if $i=k$, and $0$ if $i\neq k.$

Comment: Excellent! thank you so much.

Comment: Sure thing. Here's a link about Kronecker deltas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta Feel free to come back if you have more issues.